# why is my external css not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link an external stylesheet to all my pages but it is not rendering. It works only on my homepage but not on other pages. I am using the exact same link on all pages and it is still not working. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
    <head> 

        <title> Website name </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"> 

    </head>
```

My CSS stylesheet has only these three selectors:

```
       h1 {color:Red;}
       div p {color: gray;}
       body {background-color: yellow; font-family:arial;}
```

EDIT: I have h1 and div p on all pages.

Comment: You are sure both files are in the same.e folder and you have the rights to load that file?

Comment: PS: If it is really external ( meaning on another domain) you will get problems with the same-origin policy.

Comment: @Koogle same-origin policy does not prevent externally hosted CSS files from loading.

Comment: oh thank you! My home page is main folder and my other pages have sub folders. If so how do I link?

Comment: Just put "subfolder/stylesheet.css"

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy depending on browser and configuration. I had that problem once.

Comment: It is not working. My style sheet is in the main folder along with homepage. subfolders have files of each pages.

Comment: @Koogle Stack Overflow itself is loading CSS files from a different domain, `cdn.sstatic.net`. There's a `Content-Type` requirement, but under normal usage it's fine. Of course, this is unrelated to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the comments you say "My style sheet is in the main folder along with homepage. Subfolders have files of each pages.".

So assuming the site's folder structure is like

```
|- home.html
|- stylesheet.css
|- folder1
|------page1.html
|- folder2
|------page2.html
```

The link in `home.html` should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

and the links in `page1.html` and `page2.html` should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheet.css">
```

This just means "the CSS file is one folder above the curent one".

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheet.css">
```

inside your subfolder pages.

Answer (score 1):

place css file inside a folder name it `CSS` and place your css file inside it

And try this method

```
<head> 

        <title> Website name </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"> 

    </head>
```

**If you still have problem then check your file name and extension** are same in both files

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check your root folder may be

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```